# Grid takes a lot more time to render whenever records count is even slightly more

Tags: angular, slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

Whenever api returns even slightly more number of records, angular-slickgrid takes too much time to render resulting whole page to become unresponsive till the grid fully loads.
One of the grids contains approx 50,000 records and it literally takes 3-4 minutes to render whole grid and for that time, whole page becomes unresponsive and user can't access the page at all.
Any thoughts or idea on this? I want page to atleast remain responsive.

Comment: Please create a stackblitz reproduction of your issue with some mocked data. From what I read SlickGrid should automatically apply some virtual scroller strategy so that only visible rows + buffer should be rendered, so I assume it's something with your code that stops it from doing that.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can you please share some links or documentation regarding this strategy you r talking about? It is really difficult to reproduce my code.

Comment: I've never used the library myself - but the angular wrapper you're using is based on [this branch](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/), and this branch mentions a page with this [example with 500000 rows](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-optimizing-dataview.html) on it's readme page . So it's either the wrapper that does something wrong or your code - and if you can't even reproduce the issue, I assume the latter.

Comment: I assume when you say 'API', you're querying data in JSON from a paged web API? @TotallyNewb is right, you need to simplify your code to the essentials. Just start with an example page from the SlickGrid repo, and add the datasource to it. 98% of the time, while you are simplifying it, you'll find the bug. If you still haven't then create a randomised 50k row datasource for testing and post the code here.

Comment: It's not Angular-Slickgrid, it must be on the developer's side because this [Example 14](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/grouping) has a button to add 50k rows and once clicked it loads an additional 50k rows in a 1-2sec. If the PO Developer wants any help at all he'll have to provide some code to replicate, there's no real info in the question to help with. The only type of grid that might be slower is Tree Data structure, but even then I wouldn't expect that much slower the demo also has a button to add 25k rows (there's no code in the question to help at all)

Comment: someone create a stackblitz today for another SO question, you can base yourself on this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-slickgrid-changing-columns-issue-r6ndzh?file=angular.json), it's super useful to help answer SO questions